# Are there any standard Goodness of fit tests for regression trees, where the output is a continuous variable?

Tags: cart, goodness-of-fit

I have fitted a regression tree on my training data and would like to demonstrate that it is a good model. For now, I am doing that by calculating the RMSE between the actual values of the dependent variable and the corresponding model outputs. The dependent variable is a continuous variable.

Are there any standard Goodness of fit tests that would be better in this scenario? Are there any other metrics that should also be looked into to assess the performance of my model?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/616183/247274)